# View the list of substitution in Vim

Tags: vim, substitution

Suppose I need to substitute pattern `commands?` to its upper case version through the following extracts from Vim's README file. The following command works,

```
:%s/\vcommands?/\=toupper(submatch(0))/g
```

***Question**: How to view the changes as a list to make sure the substitution was correct?*

Here are a few attempts I tried.

1. View the [difference between the current buffer and the original file"](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Diff_current_buffer_and_the_original_file). The workflow is to save the buffer before making substitution, then do substitution, and use the command `:DiffSaved` mentioned on the linked page to see the difference. It works fine for small document. For large ones, locating the changes is hard.
2. Use `l` flag of `substitute` command. `:help :s` says the flag `l` "print(s) the text like `|:list|`." I tried this by appending flag `l` after `g` flag. It says "5 substitutions on 3 lines" and show the last line with substitutions. It looks promising, but I don't how to view each line with change(s).
3. Capture ex command output. Since `:s` is an ex command, I should be able to capture its output. This [wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output) shows the steps. It uses `redir` cmd. The output I captured is identical to the output I saw using attempt 2. Rather than showing every line with change(s), it simply says

   ```
   5 substitutions on 3 lines
   6 line editing, COMMAND typeahead display, COMMAND to display$
   ```

---

*Text for substitution example:*

```
Vi IMproved.  A clone of the UNIX text editor Vi.  Very useful
for editing programs and other plain ASCII text.  Full Vi
compatibility and includes all Ex commands.  Extra features
above Vi: Multilevel undo, multiple windows, syntax
highlighting, command line history, folding, improved command
line editing, command typeahead display, command to display
yank buffers, possibility to edit binary files, file name
stack, support for Manx QuickFix and other compiler's error
messages, shows current file name in window title, on-line
help, rectangular cut/paste, etc., etc., etc...
```

Comment: Why not first preview the changes with `:g/\vcommands?/#p` and substitute after you verified what is going to change?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers If I understood correctly, `:g/\vcommands?/#p` would print the lines containing the pattern `\vcommands?`. I want to view the *substitution* made not the pattern found.

Comment: A bit convoluted and lots of room for improvement but this might get you started `let @t=''|g/\vcommands?/sil y T|let @t = substitute(@t,'\vcommand?', '\=toupper(submatch(0))', 'g')`. After execution, the `t` register contains the lines with the substitution that has been made.

Comment: I like your idea. Is it possible to append the line number of matched pattern? I got a different idea. The workflow is search for the pattern first, e.g. `/\vcommands?'. Then substitute as usual, `:%s//\=toupper(submatch(0))/g'. The last step is the trick--run ':cwin' to open the quickfix window. I can now `:cnext` and `:cprev` to go to the next and previous substitution. This does not generate a table.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, but what about using `c` flag to confirm each individual change? This is,
`:%s/\vcommands?/\=toupper(submatch(0))/gc`

Comment: I do not like flag `c` because after confirming `y`, vim jumps to the next catch of the pattern, which could be quite away from the most recent change. As a result, it would be hard to see the changes. It might also be more efficient to do changes at once and revise the mistakes if any.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the changed line pressing 'y' and waits for keypress,
before going to next change, :%s,old,new,gicp#
No guarantees, inspired by gnu-emacs query-replace.

```
> git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git 
> cd src
> mingw32-make -f Make_ming.mak gvim.exe 
> gvim.exe -c "%s,Sun,SUNDAY,gicp#" testfile.txt
> git diff ex_cmds.c

--- a/src/ex_cmds.c
+++ b/src/ex_cmds.c
@@ -5095,6 +5095,7 @@ do_sub(exarg_T *eap)
 #endif
                ); ++lnum)
     {
+       int show_change=FALSE;
        nmatch = vim_regexec_multi(&regmatch, curwin, curbuf, lnum,
                                                       (colnr_T)0, NULL, NULL);
        if (nmatch)
@@ -5432,8 +5433,10 @@ do_sub(exarg_T *eap)
                        }
                        if (typed == 'n')
                            break;
-                       if (typed == 'y')
+                       if (typed == 'y') {
+                           show_change=TRUE;
                            break;
+                       }
                        if (typed == 'l')
                        {
                            /* last: replace and then stop */
@@ -5779,6 +5782,11 @@ skip:
                line_breakcheck();
            }

+           if (show_change) {
+               print_line(curwin->w_cursor.lnum, subflags.do_number, subflags.do_list);
+               do_sleep(10);
+               (void) plain_vgetc(); // wait for keypress
+           }
+
```